# How to check if the active object is using no material

Tags: python, scripting, materials

Is there a way, to check if the **current object** is using **no material** for cycles engine, so that the code could take a logical decision based on that!

Answer (score 2):

**Get all the materials**

```
materials = bpy.context.active_object.data.materials
```

**Count the material slots**

```
nMat = len(materials)
```

**Check if a material slot is empty** (in this case, the first slot)

```
isEmpty = not materials[0]
```